# How to get the Jquery row ID on single click

Tags: jquery

```
 var value;
    $("#Grid1").click(function(e) {
            var row = jQuery(e.target).parent();
            value= row.attr("id");
        });
        var onrowclick = function() {
        ("#Grid1").click($("#showgrid").load('/Names/Friends/satish/' +  value));
    };
```

I am trying to send the value on URL.

When I am giving like this I am not getting the output result.
Am I doing this correctly?

Is the problem that I am handling click event on same grid two times?

Comment: Are you missing some code here? Your function named onrowclick *assigns* a click handler to the grid, but it's not called in the provided code.

Comment: on value I wil get row value on that row...

Comment: pls provide the HTML portion of code!

Comment: see the new updated this may help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** in responce to your comment:

if you want assign a variable outside the click event you can do this:

```
$(function () {
  // declare the variable.. this one will hold the parent id
  var my_value;
    // now the click event...
    $("#Grid1").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // my_value now is setted outside...
             my_value = $(this).parent().attr("id");
         });

  // now for the example we observe the click event you can use it in other way!

    $('#Grid1').bind( 'click' , function() { 
      // now as you can see we are using my_value that come from outside!
     $('#showgrid').load('/Names/Friends/satish/' + my_value );

    });

});
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**

now i don't know if the `#Grid1` is inside the `#showgrid` but if this is the case, you need to use the `live()` method!

like this:

```
$("#Grid1").live( 'click' , function(e) {
// do something here as above...!
});
```

assuming:

```
<div id="this_is_parent_of_Grid1">
<a id="Grid1" href="">click</a>
</div>
```

**OR** if you use **table**

```
<table><tr>
<td id="this_is_parent_of_Grid1"><a id="Grid1">click</a></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Can i write this to get the row value in to var

var value =
    $("#Grid1").click(function(e) {
            var row = jQuery(e.target).parent();
            value= row.attr("id");
        });
I need to get the Row value in value?

thanks

Comment: by using **e.preventDefault();** let you click two times the same grid!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without seeing HTML, but I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
// Initialize variables outside of the handler
var row;
var value;

$("#Grid1").click(function(e) {
    // Assign values to variables when event handler fires
    row = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr');
    value= row.attr("id");
    $("#showgrid").load('/Names/Friends/satish/' +  value);
});

// Now you can access the local variables

function someFunction() {
    alert(value);
    alert(row.get(0));
}
```

I changed `parent()` to `closest()` since I don't know your HTML structure.

---

**EDIT:**

For clarity, I am assuming that `#Grid1` is some sort of container (`table` perhaps), and you are clicking on something in the content of a `tr`. And `#showgrid` is a separate component external to the container that displays additional info.

**EDIT:**

I'll assume from your comment that you need to access the row element and/or ID from outside the handler. I've updated the example to reflect how this can be done. Let me know if that's not what you meant.

Comment: Yes your perfect..while display ShowGrid I am passing first grid row id value to the Actionresult method.. to get that perticular users..
thanks

Comment: Can i write this to get the row value in to var var value = $("#Grid1").click(function(e) { var row = jQuery(e.target).parent(); value= row.attr("id"); }); I need to get the Row value in value? thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The way it is, you have both the row and the value of its ID stored in variables. Are you saying that you need to access the value outside of the function?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you need to explain specifically what you want to do. Just remember, `$('myElement').click(funct...` does **not** fire the code. It merely sets it up to fire when the user clicks on the element.

Answer (score 0):

what do you need to do?

```
var value;

$("#rowid").click(function() {
    value = $(this).value();
});
```

or you can try something like this:

```
var value;

$("#rowid").click(function() {
    value = $(this).value();
    $("#showgrid").html( $.load("/Names/Friends/Satish/" + value) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks,

but I want this var onrowclick.. variable bec I am assiging this on server side Rowclick evnt...

thanks

Comment: Using this method (based on ID), you would need to manually assign a click event handler to each individual row. kumar appears to have the handler assigned to a container of the rows, and is relying on bubbling to fire the code. It is a good and efficient method if you have lots of rows, or rows being frequently added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the following?

```
$("#Grid1").click(function(e) {
         var value= $(e.target).parent().attr("id");
         $("#Grid1").load('/Names/Friends/satish/' +  value);
     });
};
```

This code is still fragile, but probably does more of what you want.